# Variable shorthands

Tags: naming-conventions

Not really related to programming in general.

I don't know if this is a struggle for anybody, and there's probably an easy solution to this problem, but I couldn't find any elegant solutions.

Everyone knows that if you're a programmer, you should write readable code to save time and help yourself in the future, like giving variables better names instead of `s` or `n`.

For Example:

```cs
public void doSomething(Function<> functionToDo, int numberOfTimes)
```

instead of:

```cs
public void doIt(Function<> f, int n)
```

But sometimes, if I have a long variable name and I have to type it in an equation that makes me have to scroll right to see the whole thing, that can get frustrating.

So, my question is: **Is there any way I can define a** ***shortcut*** **variable that doesn't affect runtime or memory?**

like c++'s pre-proccesor statement #define: `#define n numberOfTimes`

Or, if there isn't solution to this at all, should I keep long variable names for the readability, or keep things short instead?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It seems your main worry here is code line length. Most languages allow you to line-wrap code as you wish, so you don't have to horizontally scroll. I'd advise keeping the long variable names.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the context where an identifier is declared. For instance, if your function *doIt* was named *doNTimes* it would be perfectly fine to name the parameters *f* and *n*. Also, they are local to the function so you don't need to search for their documentation (which should be just before or after the function header). As you mention, in choosing a name there is also a tradeoff between identifier comprehensibility and expression comprehensibility; whereas a more descriptive name increases the former and decreases the latter the opposite holds true for a short name.

If you know that your identifier is going to be used in complex expressions it's a good idea to use a shorter name. A function call with side-effects on the other hand will (should) only be a single statement so then the name can be longer.

To summarize, I would say that it's a good idea to keep formal parameters and local variables short as that make expressions easy to comprehend; the documentation is right there in the function anyway, e.g.

```
public void doNTimes(Function<> f, int n); /** apply f n times */
```

Note: In a real scenario you would also need to provide the actual parameters of *f*.